# Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() not working in embedded mono?

Tags: mono

I'm trying to embed mono in a c++ executable, and mono crashes on Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly. Any idea of what I missed ?

EDIT : using mono 3.0.3

EmbeddedMonoTest.cpp :

```
// EmbeddedMonoTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <mono/metadata/debug-helpers.h>
#include <mono/metadata/exception.h>
#include <mono/jit/jit.h>
#include <mono/metadata/assembly.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MonoDomain* domain = mono_jit_init_version ("ClassLibrary1", "v4.0.30319");
    MonoAssembly* _assembly_fbmonoengine    = mono_domain_assembly_open (domain, "ClassLibrary1.dll");  
    MonoImage* _image_fbmonoengine      = mono_assembly_get_image (_assembly_fbmonoengine);
    MonoClass* klass = mono_class_from_name(_image_fbmonoengine, "ClassLibrary1", "Class1");
    MonoMethod* test = mono_class_get_method_from_name(klass, "Test"    , 0);
    mono_runtime_invoke(test, NULL, NULL, NULL); 
    return 0;
}
```

Class1.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Test()
        {
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        }
    }
}
```

The error :

```
Unhandled exception at 0x65ad2148 in EmbeddedMonoTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x`00000008.
```

Comment: If we were talking about .NET, and given that you are hosting the runtime correctly & have loaded the assembly properly, I would consider this a bug. So maybe it might help to know the exact (build) version of Mono that you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not executing any assembly in your program, so ExecutingAssembly in that context has no meaning (a better error is needed, though).
You need to provide the usual static Main() entry point in the assembly and execute it with mono_runtime_exec_main().